# Fisher's Exact Test for 4 subgroups

Tags: binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I have a question for using Fisher's exact test for subgroups.

I have 39 subjects that was divided into 4 groups( n = 9, 5, 10, 15, respectively).

There were 3 conditions dividing the groups.
Table below shows the summary.

| Conditions | Group1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Condition A | O | X | X | X |
| Condition B | O | O | X | X |
| Condition C | O | O | O | X |

Each subjects chose between 2 options (A or B) after the treatment. So I got 4x2 contingency data as below.

| Choice | Group1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Choose A | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Choose B | 3 | 4 | 8 | 12 |

My initial hypothesis was that, **Condition A increases % choosing option A**. So I designed and conducted an experiment with only group 1 and group 4. I used Fisher's exact Test to compare them and found that there was significant difference (p<0.05).

However, I later came out with an alternative theory that, maybe condition B, C could also influence % choosing A. So I did the same experiment with group 2 and 3, and found that the result seemed similar to group 4 rather then group 1.

**How can I show that both condition B and C does not influence the "% of A-choice" significantly?**

---

ps: I am currently thinking of using the following methods:

(a) Fisher's Exact test to compare (Group 1) vs (Group 2+3+4 **combined**) to show the significant difference of % choosing exists in condition A.

(b) Fisher's Exact test to compare (Group 1+2 **combined**) vs (Group 3+4 **combined**) to show significant difference in doesn't exist in condition B.

(c) Fisher's Exact test to compare (Group 1+2+3 **combined**) vs (group 4) to show significant difference in doesn't exist in condition C.

Comment: Fisher's exact test is [not very accurate](https://www.zotero.org/groups/2199991/feh/tags/fishers-exact-test/library) for comparing two groups, so I wouldn't use it for four.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It feels like this is going to be a dumb question, but do you mean that it would be better to avoid using Fisher's exact test for comparing small number of groups?

Comment: I would avoid using Fisher's "exact" test for any use.  Its p-values are too large, e.g., if testing at $\alpha=0.05$ the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when it is true is $< 0.05$.  Ordinary Pearson $\chi^2$ works quite well.  For your particular needs I'd embed this into a model such as the polytomous (multinomial) logistic model which allows you to compute any contrast you need, and even get simultaneous coverage confidence intervals over multiple contrasts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it out.

Comment: Would it be possible to use multinomial logistic model? Because independent variables (condition A, B, C) might be conflicted with the assumption of multicollinearity, since All subjects with condition A also have condition  B and C.

Comment: Or did you mean I should try to make a model predict conditions (which would then be dependent variable) using choices (which would be independent variable)?